# C/C++ configuration problem in android studio 4 after gradle sync

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

I am trying to integrate native (C++) OpenCV code into my project. I am following [this](https://github.com/leadrien/opencv_native_androidstudio) project on github. After I click refresh linked C++ projects the compiler exits with exit code 1.

```
2:48 AM Gradle sync finished in 3 s 67 ms

2:48 AM C/C++ Configuration Problem
                native-lib | debug | x86
                Compiler exited with error code 1: /home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -xc++ --target=i686-none-linux-android24 --gcc-toolchain=/home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS -isystem /home/user/Downloads/forLinux/android studio/opencv-4.3.0-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
                Android (5900059 based on r365631c) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 207d7abc1a2abf3ef8d4301736d6a7ebc224a290) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
                Target: i686-none-linux-android24
                Thread model: posix
                
    Dir: /home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin 
Found candidate GCC installation: /home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x 
Found candidate GCC installation: /home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x 
Selected GCC installation: /home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x Candidate multilib: .;@m32 
Selected multilib: .;@m32 clang++: error: no such file or directory: 'studio/opencv-4.3.0-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include'
```

Answer (score 0):

The folder containing open-cv sdk had a space in its name. Removing the space solved the error.